# Normal estimation in C++ with CGAL framework

Tags: c++, cgal

I have been using CGAL to estimate the normals of a set of points with the `CGAL::mst_orient_normals` function, but it is too slow. I even tried the example in the documentation. It estimates normals in a set of points corresponding to a sphere and it takes more than 1 hour. I want to know if this is normal or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

- If you using Visual C++/Studio for compilation, make sure you running in **Release** mode. It is a lot faster than **Debug** mode for template code that is built upon STL.
- Make sure you are using the simplest **kernel** that will estimate the normals. For example, the `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` will be slower than `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`